# ConfigurationManager not saving ConnectionString in App.config

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to programmatically update the connections string in my App.config file.

I can read the value perfectly but I cannot seem to update the value for some reason.

My App.config look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="TPAPI.Properties.Settings.TruePotentialConnectionString"
    connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=TruePotential;User ID=sa;Password=password"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I can read it with this:

```
txtConnectionString.Text = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TPAPI.Properties.Settings.TruePotentialConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

BUT when I try and write a new value nothing happens.

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["TPAPI.Properties.Settings.TruePotentialConnectionString"].ConnectionString = txtConnectionString.Text;
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: When you say "nothing happens", what do you mean? I tried out your exact example code and it works fine. The thing to note here is that `config.Save()` DOES NOT update the physical file, it only updates your `config` object. After doing `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection()`, you should be able to see your updated connection string using your `config` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the same problem as u have but if u want u can read this for a moment, It's not my own answer.

Credits:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13133034/3239917

> I think what is happening is that you are testing in Visual Studio, it
>   copys the App.Config to your Debug/Release directory and renames it
>   YourApplication.vshost.exe.config which gets reset each time you start
>   your application. Try running the executable outside of Visual Studio
>   which will use the YourApplication.exe.config file and see if that
>   works for you. Your Code is working for me and retaining your changes
>   on application restart if I run it outside of Visual Studio.